# find and change elements of a column with another column in a text

Tags: python, pandas, text, replace

I am trying to code an abbreviations replacer. I am not very skillful at Python and all I came up with is the code below:

```py
import pandas as pd
import re
abbr = pd.read_excel('/content/drive/MyDrive/abbraviations_eng.xlsx')
old = abbr['abbr']
new = abbr['long']
k=0
def abbr_clean(text):
    global k
    for i in range(0,len(abbr)):
        for word in text.split():
            if old[i] == word:
                text = re.sub(str(old[i]), str(new[i]), text)
                k+=1
    return text
```

I know it is a very primitive and slow way to use a loop here. Abbreviations and their long forms are in an excel file. I look for every abbreviation in text and replace it if found. I have a text of 1600000 lines. How can I make it faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python loops and the `split` function are slow, but calling `re.sub` for each match is clearly the source of slowdown here. Indeed, a new string of about 1.6 MB is created for each match (possibly thousand times or more). Because of this, the algorithm complexity is quadratic (`O(k * len(text))`).

Here is a much better algorithm running in linear time (`O(len(text))`):

```py
import pandas as pd
import re
abbr = pd.read_excel('/content/drive/MyDrive/abbraviations_eng.xlsx')
old = abbr['abbr']
new = abbr['long']
assert len(old) == len(new)
repDict = {str(old[i]): str(new[i]) for i in range(len(old))}
k = 0

def replaceCallback(m):
    global k
    k += 1
    return repDict[m.group(0)]

def abbr_clean(text):
    # Create a big regexp searching for all old abbreviations.
    pattern = re.compile("|".join([re.escape(k) for k in sorted(repDict,key=len,reverse=True)]), flags=re.DOTALL)

    # Call the function replaceCallback every time an old abbreviation is 
    # found and replace it by the new abbreviation.
    return pattern.sub(replaceCallback, text)
```

With few abbreviations and many replacements on a 1.6 MB text, this implementation is several order of magnitude faster.

PS: this implementation assumes that the abbreviations are not conflicting (eg. "ab" vs "abc") or combining each other during the replacement.